# pandas - cumulative median

Tags: python, pandas, math, accumulate

I was wondering if there is any pandas equivalent to `cumsum()` or `cummax()` etc. for median: e.g. `cummedian()`.

So that if I have, for example this dataframe:

```
   a
1  5
2  7
3  6
4  4
```

what I want is something like:

```
df['a'].cummedian()
```

which should output:

```
5
6  
6 
5.5
```

Comment: If you're looking for a fast solution, I'm betting divakar's would be it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Nah, mine looks slower! That `np.nanmedian` isn't helping much.

Comment: @OP, please test all our solutions on a large data set of say, 100000 elements. The solution that works best for small data may not always scale.

Comment: @Binayamin Even, Please take a look at my answer. I've added timings for large data, and `expanding.median` is the clear winner.

Comment: If you have to perform expanding medians for multiple columns, it is even easier to generalise with `expanding`. On the other hand, a pure python function lacking any vectorisation benefits will scale linearly, leading to an even larger slowdown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `expanding.median` -

```
df.a.expanding().median()

1    5.0
2    6.0
3    6.0
4    5.5
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.arange(1000000)})

%timeit df['a'].apply(cummedian())
1 loop, best of 3: 1.69 s per loop

%timeit df.a.expanding().median()
1 loop, best of 3: 838 ms per loop
```

The winner is `expanding.median` by a huge margin. Divakar's method is memory intensive and suffers memory blowout at this size of input.

Comment: Posted the solution you were looking in here :)

Comment: It was hard to get the expected output from your question using `strides`.

Answer (score 2):

We could create nan filled subarrays as rows with a `strides` based function, like so -

```
def nan_concat_sliding_windows(x):
    n = len(x)
    add_arr = np.full(n-1, np.nan)
    x_ext = np.concatenate((add_arr, x))
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    nrows = len(x_ext)-n+1
    s = x_ext.strides[0]
    return strided(x_ext, shape=(nrows,n), strides=(s,s))
```

Sample run -

```
In [56]: x
Out[56]: array([5, 6, 7, 4])

In [57]: nan_concat_sliding_windows(x)
Out[57]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,   5.],
       [ nan,  nan,   5.,   6.],
       [ nan,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   4.]])
```

Thus, to get sliding median values for an array `x`, we would have a vectorized solution, like so-

```
np.nanmedian(nan_concat_sliding_windows(x), axis=1)
```

Hence, the final solution would be -

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]: 
a
1  5
2  7
3  6
4  4

In [55]: pd.Series(np.nanmedian(nan_concat_sliding_windows(df.a.values), axis=1))
Out[55]: 
0    5.0
1    6.0
2    6.0
3    5.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hmm, I knew there was a way with strides. You got it.

Comment: Okay, I timed this answer, and it ended up failing for my test input. I don't suppose there's any way to make this less memory intensive, right? :(

Answer (score 0):

A faster solution for the specific cumulative median

```
In [1]: import timeit

In [2]: setup = """import bisect
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: def cummedian():
   ...:     l = []
   ...:     info = [0, True]
   ...:     def inner(n):
   ...:         bisect.insort(l, n)
   ...:         info[0] += 1
   ...:         info[1] = not info[1]
   ...:         median = info[0] // 2
   ...:         if info[1]:
   ...:             return (l[median] + l[median - 1]) / 2
   ...:         else:
   ...:             return l[median]
   ...:     return inner
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(20)})"""

In [3]: timeit.timeit("df['cummedian'] = df['a'].apply(cummedian())",setup=setup,number=100000)
Out[3]: 27.11604686321956

In [4]: timeit.timeit("df['expanding'] = df['a'].expanding().median()",setup=setup,number=100000)
Out[4]: 48.457676260100335

In [5]: 48.4576/27.116
Out[5]: 1.7870482372031273
```

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because your post has misleading timings.

Comment: In future, please _test_ your function on _large_ data, before claiming that your function is faster. This becomes even slower if you're performing an expanding median on multiple columns, because your function does not vectorize in any way, you'd have to apply them linearly.